Sum of infinitely many convex functions
Why sum of infinitely many convex functions might not be convex? Can you please include an example I couldn't find an example of such a function

Could you please provide a bit more context -- where did you see this result claimed?

My professor claimed this in class. I couldn't find it elsewhere

This isn't true (unless you consider "strictly convex" functions).

It is a false statement, sum of infinitely many convex functions is always convex.
Consider an infinite sequence of convex functions $(f_n)$, $f_n:X\to \mathbb {R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $X$ is a convex subset of a real vector space. Assume that $s_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x)$ is a pointwise convergent sequence of functions and $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n(x) = s(x)$. It is easy to prove that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a function $s_n$ must be convex. So by the definition of the convexity for all $x, y \in X$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$
$$s_n\big((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y \big) \leq (1-\lambda)s_n(x) + \lambda s_n(y)$$
As $n\to\infty$ we get
$$s \big((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y \big) \leq (1-\lambda)s(x) + \lambda s (y)$$
what proves that $s(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(x)$ is a convex function too.
